# How to calculate dynamically appended table rows using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, function

I am new to jQuery and I am stuck.
I am dynamically adding rows to a jQuery table. I want to calculate each row (length * width) = row-total
I want to SUM each column and show a grand total at the bottom of the table.

I also want to dynamically add a new row when a user inputs a number in the second to last width input. So I do not have to click a button.

I have figured out how to append rows to the table but I cannot get the calculation to work.
Here is my work, and a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wesC/2a41a1tv/9/)!

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed tab_logic turf" id="turf">
    <thead>
        <tr class="persist headings">
            <td colspan="3"><a class="toggle" tabindex="997" href="#">Turf Measurements</a></td>
            <td tabindex="998"><a class="toggle" href="#">Show / Hide</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="headings">
            <td class="heading">Turf</td>
            <td class="heading">Length</td>
            <td class="heading">Width</td>
            <td  class="heading">Total</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="grand-total">
            <td>Combined Totals</td>
            <td class="length-total"></td>
            <td class="width-total"></td>
            <td class="table-total" ></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tfoot>
    <tr class="grand-total persist">           
            <td>Combined Totals</td>
            <td class="length-total"></td>
            <td class="width-total"></td>
            <td class="table-total" ></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr id='addr1' class="calculation visible">
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="length">
            <input type="text" class="length form-control input-md" value="" tabindex="1" /></td>
            <td class="width">
            <input type="text" class="width form-control input-md" type="text" value="" tabindex="2" /></td>
            <td class="row-total"><input type="text" class="row-total form-control" value="" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calculation visible">
            <td>2</td>
            <td class="length">
            <input type="text" class="length form-control input-md" value="" tabindex="3" /></td>
            <td class="width">
            <input type="text" class="width form-control input-md" value="" tabindex="4" />
            </td>
            <td class="row-total"><input type="text" class="row-total form-control" value="" readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='addr2' class="calculation visible">
    </tbody>
</table>
<div><a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>  Add Row</a></div>
<div><a class="btn btn-default pull-left calculate" title="calculate row">Calculate</a></div>
<div><a  href="#" id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>  Delete Row</a></div>
```

I have two different pieces of code I was trying to use to create the calculations.

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=2;
  var ti=5;
 $("#add_row").click(function(){
  $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td class='length'><input name='length"+i+"' type='text' class='length form-control input-md' value='' tabindex='"+(ti++)+"' /></td><td class='width'><input  name='width"+i+"' type='text' class='width form-control input-md' value='' tabindex='"+(ti++)+"' /></td><td class='row-total'><input type='text' class='row-total form-control' value='' readonly /></td>");

  $('#turf tr:last').after('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'" class="calculation visible"></tr>');
  i++;
```

});//end add_row click

```
 $("#delete_row").click(function(){
     if(i>1){
     $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
     i--;
     }
 }); //end delete_row click
});//end function`
```

Is what adds the rows.  I would prefer to have it add rows dynamically versus needing to click a button.

And this is what I am using to calculate with.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.calculation').change('click', function() {
    $('.turf').find('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
        var l = $(this).find('input.length').val();
        var w = $(this).find('input.width').val();
        var dateTotal = (l * w);
        $(this).find('input.row-total').val(dateTotal);
    }); //END .each
    return false;
}); // END click 
});
```

I have another piece of calculation code in the fiddle but it is commented out because I am getting lost trying to go between two different pieces of code.

Comment: You have class="turf" and id="turf" use one or the other. If you have ID, try `$('#turf').on("change",".calculation",function() ...`

Comment: I changed it to have #turf.  Still no change to the ability to calculate.  Updated http://jsfiddle.net/wesC/2a41a1tv/10/

Answer (score 2):

You need to delegate the event to the container and then point at the dynamically added object using a class. Also it is `.on("click",...)` (button, radio or checkbox) or `.on("change",...)` (select or text field) not `.change("click",...)`

Try this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mn55Lxho/)

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function recalc() {
    var lt=0,wt=0,tt=0;
    $("#turf").find('tr').each(function () {
        var l = $(this).find('input.length').val();
        var w = $(this).find('input.width').val();
        var dateTotal = (l * w);
        $(this).find('input.row-total').val(dateTotal?dateTotal:"");
        wt+=isNumber(w)?parseInt(w,10):0;
        lt+=isNumber(l)?parseInt(l,10):0;
        tt+=isNumber(dateTotal)?dateTotal:0;
    }); //END .each
    $("#length-grand-total").html(lt);
    $("#width-grand-total").html(wt);
    $("#table-grand-total").html(tt);
}
```

and add

```
$("#turf").on("click", ".calculation", recalc);
$("#turf").on("keyup blur", ".form-control", recalc);
// add a row if a length is entered in the last row
$("#turf").on("keyup",".length:last", function() { 
    if (!$(this).data("done")) { // only do this once per field
      $(this).data("done",true);
      addRow();
    }
});
$("#delete_row").on("click",delRow);
```

to your load

and change tfoot to

```
<tfoot>
    <tr class="grand-total persist">
        <td>Combined Totals</td>
        <td id="length-grand-total"></td>
        <td id="width-grand-total"></td>
        <td id="table-grand-total"></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: To add a row based on data entered into a width field so they don't need to click a button I know I need to change this but, to what?
'$("#add_row").click(function(){'

Comment: Could you help with the adding row without button click issue?

Comment: Sure. What triggers the adding? Entering data in the one but last field?

Comment: See update. If you need the test for something entered it is more complex. Now I just add on keyup, so in principle it adds a field even if you type a letter.

Comment: They should only enter a number.  If I have validation on the input it shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: Sure, but you do not have validation at the moment

Comment: I will when I put it up so I should be fine.  If the input creates a new row, why does the html still need the links present to make the form calculate?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by links? the calculate can be deleted, the add button too but then you need to change  $("#add_row").click(); to addRow() and move the click event to a function called addRow()

Comment: Excellent. It is much cleaner now.  I will use it as my tutorial to completely figure out what is going on and how to assign events to functions.

Comment: I totally spaced and realized I can't put more than one table on a page. What would I need to change to have 3 tables on the page at once? id="fb", id="gc", and the current id="turf".  Or would I create 3 different pieces of code with new id's?

Comment: No. Do not repeat the code. However it is not trivial to add.
You will have to remove the id=turf and use the class. Then you can access the table you are in with $(this) like I did in `$(this).find('input.row-total')` - You also need to use classes for the totals and pass the context: `var $thisTable=$(this); ..... $(".length-grand-total", $thisTable).html(lt);`

Comment: OK. I do need some more help.  I have tried the things you said above.  When I add an additional table, the tab order goes between two tables.  The delete deletes rows from both tables. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wesC/cu51jcza/3/

Comment: It is very late here. I will look tomorrow. Where is the delete? Will you have one per table? I suggest a delete per row, then you just delete the parent row

Comment: Delete can be per row or per table. Currently it is hidden with css.

Comment: Try delRow($(this)) and use (not tested) `function delRow(del) {
    var t = del.parent.prev();
    if (numRows > 1) {
        $(".addr" + (numRows - 1),t).remove();
        numRows--;
    }
}` You would need to calculate numrows instead of having a var.

Comment: My latest attempt. http://jsfiddle.net/cu51jcza/8/ I have tried what you suggested. But, clearly I am in over my head. I thought this would be a simple problem. (For me it is not.) I would greatly appreciate your help in solving these last few issues and would reward the effort promptly.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Give me a bit of time.

Comment: What is critical for me is tabbing between cells within a table, and calculation of totals.  Deleting of rows is secondary.

Comment: Ok, Calculation, some navigation, deletion is done. What about row-totals? http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vjt43vuc/

Comment: Yes Row Totals are Important.

Comment: Ok, I think we are pretty close. Please see same URL - it even recalcs if you delete a row with values

Comment: I think that covers it for me.  I like that it recalcs when you delete a row.  The only thing it might be missing for others is validation and $(".table-total").val(sum.toFixed(2)); but for me it is not important.

Comment: OK.  I have discovered a problem with this.  Each table has different input names but we are appending with the same HTML for each table.

Comment: Each table has different input "name" but this appends the same HTML for each table.  So, if the input of table1 is supposed to be:
`... name='wpcf-measure-turf-length[] ...` and table2 is
`... name='wpcf-measure-fb-length[] ...` and table 3 is `... name='wpcf-measure-gc-length[] ...`  It doesn't work as it appends the same inputs for every table. Same with width and row total also.

Comment: Ok, I can take the name from the table ID (or from a previous field name but then delete may not delete the first row of inputs- I will fix this in a few hours (very early morning here)

Comment: Delete is secondary. The actual input is now structured like this `<input post='cpt-measurement' name='wpcf-measure-fb-length[] length" + numRows + "' type='number' class='length form-control input-md' value='' tabindex='" + (ti++) + "' />` to match my classes.

Comment: I tried `var table2 = '<tr><td class="row-num">' ... $table.append(table2);` but that didnt work.  It appended var table1 then var table 2 right after.

Comment: Re:delete - if I were to take the new name from existing names in the form, then it would not be a good idea to allow the deletion of all rows with inputs. Anyway, solution:
1. give each table the ID you wish the names of the fields should have, here turf and fb.
2. change the $("[id^table]") to just $(".table") since they both have that class.
3. Add `var fieldIdentifier = "wpcf-measure-"+$table.attr("id");` just before the creation of the rows 
4. You PROBABLY want `wpcf-measure-turf-length[]` and `wpcf-measure-fb-length[]` since PHP prefers that. Here:http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/osmg1q6e/

Comment: The inputs work perfectly now with the individual tables. The delete works but does not recalc like it did before.  Plus it goes back to the top of the page on delete.

Comment: Last issue first: add an (e) and an e.preventDefault() to delRow: `function delRow(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();`

Comment: And now I click `$table.find(".calculation").click();` instead of just the last row. http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/osmg1q6e/

Comment: Ok. That is working well.  Thanks for commenting the code it helps in understanding what is going on.

Comment: YW - I have added some more comments into the fiddle